# Staticy Turtle Beach Mic

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, headset

I've views tens of threads and links online about hissing Turtle Beaches and such. Easy solution was that I plugged the USB part into the wall and the mic / audio in my PC. Now that was the solution to get my Mic not being staticy when I talk and it fixed the hiss in my headphones.

The problem is - I can't adjust the audio via the controller on my headset. All my audio is max and it's at a reasonable level - not too low but it's not extremely high - I want it to be louder. If I plug my USB back into my PC I get control over my volume again. Is there something I can do to make the audio louder on my Beaches with the USB pluged in externally?

I have X12 beaches.

Comment: I'd wonder how it would work with a powered usb hub - you'd be getting power from a wall, but signal from the computer. Might also help to mention the mic model, and/or better yet reference some of these threads

Comment: Soundsike you have interference of some kind have you tried a different USB port.  This got rid of a similar sound on the same product

Comment: @Ramhound - different USB ports produce the same problem. I've tried running it through an extension too back to my computer but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - have you tried unplugging all other usb devices except the headset?

Comment: @Ramhound I haven't but the only other things I have in there - on the backside of the tower are my mouse and keyboard. I guess I haven't tried pluggin in my mic into any of the USB ports in the back though.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - I would try that.